# JQuery UI Variables in Element Initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm working on a site that uses JQuery UI to display some tabs and accordions, but I'm running into a road block when I use a variable inside an elements initialization.  Basically, I need to read some numbers out of a URL `stuff/1/0` and selectively activate parts of an accordion based on them.  This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Get URL
var href = window.location.pathname;

//Get Segments
var segs = href.split('/');

if(segs.length > 2)
{
    var active_tab = segs[segs.length - 1];
    var active_unit = segs[segs.length - 2];

    alert(active_tab);
    alert(active_unit);

    //Check if its a number
    if(!isNaN(active_unit))
    {
        //Accordions
        $( ".accordion" ).accordion
        ({
            active: active_unit,
            autoHeight: false,
            collapsible: true
        });
    }

    //Check if its a number
    if(!isNaN(active_tab))
    {
        //Tabs
        $( ".tabs" ).tabs
        ({
            selected: active_tab
        });
    }
}

});
```

But, this doesn't seem to affect the accordion at all, even though I am successfully getting the URL segments.  Obviously, this is because the active_tab/active_unit variables are not being parsed into the accordion/tab set up.  Is there some other way to accomplish this?  Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values you parsed out of the url are strings. You need to parse them into numbers:

```
var active_tab = parseInt(segs[segs.length - 1], 10);
var active_unit = parseInt(segs[segs.length - 2], 10);
```

It probably wasn't working because the accordian plugin was expecting a number.